# Applying Law of Cosines to get Polarization Identity

Tags: linear-algebra

I am teaching myself some basic linear algebra using MATH51 textbook and I got to a problem which states following:

> The parallelogram in R3 formed by two 3-vectors v and w. The vectors
>   on the diagonals of the parallelogram are v - w and v + w.
>
> For the case n = 2, apply the Law of Cosines to each of the triangles
>   made by cutting theparallelogram in half along a diagonal (regard the
>   chosen diagonal as the side opposite the “angle” being used in the Law
>   of Cosines) to establish the polarization identity.

After some Googling I got some intution (although not a clear one)  to use dot product of **v** and **w**, the thing is dot product operation has not been introduced yet. Is there any way to use Law of Cosines to get Polarization Identity without using dot product?

I am including a screenshot with the [entire problem and a diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmEl6.jpg) for better illustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mito
What is called "polarization identity" in your book is usually called parallelogram identity (the polarization identity has to do with recovering the dot product from the length). You have two triangles. One has sides $||v||$, $||w||$ and $||v+w||$ and the other one has sides $||v||$, $||w||$ and $||v-w||$. Since they form a parallelogram, the angles opposite to $||v-w||$ and $||v+w||$ are supplementary so they have opposite cosines. When you apply the law of cosines you get 
$$
||v-w||^2=||v||^2+||w||^2-2||v|||w||\cos A
$$
and 
$$
||v+w||^2=||v||^2+||w||^2-2||v|||w||\cos (\pi - A)=||v||^2+||w||^2+2||v|||w||\cos A
$$
By adding these two you get what you need.